# Why does ACHartEngine LineGraph doesn^t show me any Graph when i use API 10

Tags: android, achartengine, android-support-library

I am trying to use ACHartEngine in my Android Application. Everything works fine when start the app with API 14 but as soon as i use the LineChart or BarChart below API 14 it doesn`t show any Graph.
Maybe someone has experienced the same problem?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {

    setupView_1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_setup1, container, false);

startPowerGraph();

    return setupView_1;
}

private void startPowerGraph() {

    setupChart();
    //Checking if i am connected via Bluetooth
    if (BT.isConnected()) {
        // Start plotting chart
        new ChartTask().execute();
    }
}

public void setupChart() {

    // Creating an XYSeries for Visits
    visitsSeries = new XYSeries("Charging Power");

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
    visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
    // visitsRenderer.setFillBelowLine(true);// needed for area chart??

    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);// to fit in ScrollVIew

    multiRenderer.setChartTitle(setupView_1.getResources().getString(R.string.chartTitle));
    multiRenderer.setXTitle(setupView_1.getResources().getString(R.string.chartXAchse));
    multiRenderer.setYTitle(setupView_1.getResources().getString(R.string.chartYAchse));
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);

    multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    // multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    // multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(100);
    //
    // multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    // multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(10);

    multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(2);

    // Adding visitsRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to
    // multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the SetUpCharging_Page1 Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) setupView_1.findViewById(R.id.Power_LinearLayout_Graph);

    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(mFragmentActivity, dataset, multiRenderer);
    // mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getBarChartView(
    // mFragmentActivity, dataset, multiRenderer, Type.STACKED);
    // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout

    chartContainer.addView(mChart);

}

public class ChartTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    // Generates dummy data in a non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int i = 0;
        int pulse = 100;
        try {
            do {
                String[] values = new String[2];

                // get Actual chargepower
                int visits = getPowerKW();
                if (getPowerKW() > multiRenderer.getYAxisMax()) {
                    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(getPowerKW() + 2);

                }
                if (getPowerKW() < multiRenderer.getYAxisMax()) {
                    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(getPowerKW());
                }

                values[0] = Integer.toString(i);
                values[1] = Integer.toString(visits);

                double maxX = visitsSeries.getMaxX();
                double minX = maxX - i; // deltaX is your required
                                        // x-range
                double maxY = visitsSeries.getMinY();
                double minY = visitsSeries.getMaxY();

                multiRenderer.setRange(new double[] { -minX, maxX, -maxY, minY });

                if (BT.isConnected()) {
                    publishProgress(values);
                    Thread.sleep(pulse);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mFragmentActivity, "Chart is waiting for Bluetooth Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } while (pause);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Plotting generated data in the graph
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        visitsSeries.add(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
        mChart.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay problem solved! The problem was/is that in API < 14 in my case, the LineGraph won`t work in a ScrollView. It just won`t show up. For API 14 it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay new Update!

It`s not about the ScrollView which doesn`t work with the Chart. For API > 10 u can edit

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

in your .xml File or do it in your java code

```
DialRenderer dialRenderer;
dialRenderer.setInScroll(true);
```

But for API 10 this doesn`t work in my case. So
i fixed it by using following code:

```
mChart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 250));
```

Note that i have used 250 or any other fix int value. If i use

```
mChart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

it won`t work again .

Maybe somebody could explain me this weird problem :P